# Conjuction template doesn't short circuit

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, short-circuiting

I want to be able to evaluate whether a function accepts one argument of type int, and whether it returns void. To that end I used `std::conjunction` since I believed it was supposed to short-circuit and not evaluate the second ill-formed expression in case the function is not callable with one argument of type int, but for some reason I get a compiler error:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
template<typename Function>
struct oneArgVoid
{
    static constexpr bool value = std::conjunction_v<std::is_invocable<Function, int>, std::is_void<std::invoke_result_t<Function, int>>>;
};

int main()
{
    auto l1 = [](auto x) {};
    std::cout << oneArgVoid<decltype(l1)>::value << "\n";
    auto l2 = [](auto x) {return 1; };
    std::cout << oneArgVoid<decltype(l2)>::value << "\n";
    auto l3 = [](auto x, auto y) {};
    std::cout << oneArgVoid<decltype(l3)>::value << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Note that if `oneArgVoid` is not called on `l3` the code compiles. Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/8BUfpT

I do not use boost, so I cannot use `mpl::eval_if`. But I thought that `std::conjunction` was supposed to short circuit here, am I wrong?

Considering HolyBlackCat's suggestion, here's something even stranger: https://godbolt.org/z/2SUij-

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Doesn't seem to work as expected: https://godbolt.org/z/EL6Ci4
Seems like int is convertible to void? `Determines whether Fn can be invoked with the arguments ArgTypes... to yield a result that is convertible to R.`

Comment: Huh, my bad. I should've checked the docs first.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I don't think you were wrong, int should not be convertible to void: https://godbolt.org/z/zJxI94

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like `std::conjunction` short-circuits only on the values of the types, the types themselves still have to be well-formed. So this: `std::is_void<std::invoke_result_t<Function, int>>` is actually rightfully illegal here. Due to that with the modification:

```
template<typename Function>
struct argVoid
{
    static constexpr bool value = std::is_void_v<std::invoke_result_t<Function, int>>;
};

template<typename Function>
struct oneArgVoid
{
    static constexpr bool value = std::conjunction_v<std::is_invocable<Function, int>, argVoid<Function>>;
};
```

It works, since the ill-formed expression is now in the value variable, which means it doesn't get evaluated due to the short-circuit.