# is_invocable_r ignoring the return parameter

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

In a comment on my question regarding `std::conjunction` not short-circuiting ([Conjuction template doesn't short circuit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57018826/conjuction-template-doesnt-short-circuit?noredirect=1#comment100568682_57018826)), I was recommended `std::is_invocable_r` as a workaround to my problem there. However as I tried to use it, I uncovered some very strange behaviour. For instance this code fails both asserts:

```
#include <type_traits>

int main()
{
    static_assert(!std::is_invocable_r_v<void, int(int), int>);
    static_assert(std::is_convertible_v<int,void>);
    return 0;
}
```

Note the description of `is_invocable_r` on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_invocable):

> Determines whether `Fn` can be invoked with the arguments `ArgTypes...` to yield a result that is convertible to `R`.

Clearly `int` is not convertible to `void`, and the second assert confirms it. The question is why does `std::is_invocable_r_v<void, int(int), int>` produce a `true` value then. Here is a live example: https://godbolt.org/z/HywH7D

Note that one can use `std::is_void_v<std::invoke_result_t<int(int),int>>` to get the correct answer here (https://godbolt.org/z/YMvc47), but this is not my question. (And it doesn't solve my problem from the conjunction question).

Comment: You might read [Callable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Callable) for the definition of `INVOKE` which has indeed special behavior for `void`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right after

> Determines whether `Fn` can be invoked with the arguments `ArgTypes...` to yield a result that is convertible to `R`. ...

it gives a more strict definition:

> ... Formally, determines whether `INVOKE<R>(declval<Fn>(), declval<ArgTypes>()...)` is well formed when treated as an unevaluated operand, where `INVOKE` is the operation defined in *[Callable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Callable)*

And in *[Callable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Callable)* it's explained that `INVOKE<void>` is a special case. Rather than implicitly converting the return value to `R`, it uses `static_cast<void>(...)` (which is well-formed for any return type).

Comment: Wait `static_cast<void>(...)` works for any return type, but `is_convertible<int,void>` is false? How do those two agree?

Comment: Just ignore the *"Determines whether Fn can be invoked with the arguments ArgTypes... to yield a result that is convertible to R."* part. As I see it, the page attempts to give you a simple imprecise explanation (*"result ... is convertible to R"*), and then goes into details of what exactly that means (if `R` is not `void`, result has to be implicitly convertible to `R`, otherwise result can have any type).